Issue with using SSH with jump host
From outside my network I can access my outside-facing server using a public-key with:
ssh me@entry.com
From that shell, I can then access another server on the network (typing in the password) with:
ssh me@192.168.0.4 -p 12345
However, if I try to do this in one line, I get an error:
ssh -A -J me@entry.com me@192.168.0.4:12345
The error I get is:

channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535

What could be causing that?

me@192.168.0.4:12345 is not a valid destination. The right syntax is either [user@]hostname or ssh://[user@]hostname[:port]. Try this:
ssh -J me@entry.com ssh://me@192.168.0.4:12345

-p does not apply to jump hosts, only to the final destination; so in this case you can as well use -p you are familiar with:
ssh -p 12345 -J me@entry.com me@192.168.0.4

Note -J does not create a daisy chain like your "manual" method did.
